# How to pass variable when dispatching fetch function in react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have react-redux app which fetching data from my node server, each time i need to fetch something i have to create same action where i change value in fetch, here is questions: How i can pass a variable in order to avoid duplicate code in such situation?

```
export function fetchProducts() {
return dispatch => {
  dispatch(fetchProductsBegin());
  return fetch("/api/followers")
    .then(handleErrors)
    .then(res => res.json().then(console.log(res)))
    .then(json => {
      dispatch(fetchProductsSuccess(json));
      return json;
    })
    .catch(error => dispatch(fetchProductsError(error)));
};
  }
```

Then i call fetchProduct:

```
class ProductList extends React.Component {  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchProducts());
  }
```

I want to have a result that where i call fetchProducts and put a variable, then each time using same action.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following:

```
// in component: 
this.props.dispatch(fetchProducts(id));
// in function
export function fetchProducts(id) {
```

Moreover, you can use

```
class ProductList extends React.Component {  
  componentDidMount() {
   this.props. fetch(id);
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  fetch: (id) => dispatch(fetchProducts(id))
});
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ProductList)
```

Comment: In action are you accepting argument like `function fetchProducts(id) {` ?

Comment: I already tried something like this, when i create const id = "/api/followers" in component, then i remove "/api/followers" from the fetch in funtion and pass id to fetchProducts in function, i got: Error! Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': 1 argument required, but only 0 present.

Comment: please share code on code sandbox, with some api e.g. github

Comment: Your error suggests that the action is not getting argument. Please try to console and check argument in action

Comment: _italic_ **bold** `test`

Answer (score 0):

> About your code struct, you should use Axios library to call API, use
>   promise for wait API call instead of dispatch fetchProductsBegin.
>
> ```
> in this case, you can rewrite the code as below:
> ```

```
export function fetchProducts(id) {
return dispatch => {
  dispatch(fetchProductsBegin(id));
  return fetch(`/api/followers/${id}`)
  //...
}
```

> call function

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchProducts(id));
  }
```

Comment: Hey, this one is very simple and just working fine, however now i stuck with another problem, then later in redux component i have action creator as below:export const fetchProductsSuccess = messages => ({
  type: FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
  payload: { messages }
});
How i can use here variable as well?

Comment: i don't clear you question but here is some hint may help:
1. when you define action you can pass as much params as you want. see this
https://redux.js.org/basics/actions
2. you must create reducer to handle action by type and change data into state. see this
https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers

Comment: It's all done, but i want to use each time same action, you resolve fetch issue so now i can use it for any url i want, but this component also have action creator. Please see my code in github: [https://github.com/fmpro12/react] I want to use same action for different data.

Comment: i can't find any ProductList class to refer your code.
what do you mean about: same actions, different data?
each time you fetch product new data will be get.
if you want other data (not product) just write other action (with different type) and use other reducer for store that data.